# Why do HashSets behave differently in Java 8 and Java 9+?

Tags: java, java-8, java-9

When trying to remove objects wrapped in iterator Java 8 and Java 9+ behave differently. Consider the following example:

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

class Scratch {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Date> dates = new HashSet<>();
    dates.add(new Date(100));
    dates.add(new Date(200));

    for (Date date : dates) {
        System.out.println("Initial "+date.getTime()+":"+date.hashCode());
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+42);
        System.out.println("Mutated "+date.getTime()+":"+date.hashCode()+"\n");
    }

    System.out.println("Size before remove iteration: "+dates.size());
    Iterator<Date> iterator = dates.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Date date = iterator.next();
        System.out.println("In loop: "+date.getTime()+":"+date.hashCode());
        iterator.remove();
    }
    System.out.println("Size after remove iteration: "+dates.size());
  }
}
```

After mutating objects inside the HashSet Java 8 refuses to remove them using iterator, check the size after removal loop.
Java 8 output:

```
Initial 100:100
Mutated 142:142

Initial 200:200
Mutated 242:242

Size before remove iteration: 2
In loop: 142:142
In loop: 242:242
Size after remove iteration: 2
```

Java 9+ output is same as above but:

```
Size after remove iteration: 0
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Note: You are modifying an object's hash key once it's already been added to a collection. This is almost guaranteed to cause malfunctions of some sort. Something as trivial as adjusting the default number of hash buckets in `HashMap` could cause this.

Comment: They probably did change something.  But the change is guaranteed to ensure consistent results when used correctly, not to ensure consistent behavior when used incorrectly.

Comment: Compare the source of the class in both Java 8 and Java 9 and find out! As Chrylis indicates, changes to the hashcode could cause issues, and it looks like Java 9 handles things differently compared to Java 8, which could mean that removal through an iterator is no longer sensitive to the hash code change, or something else changed. However, you are basically relying on undefined behaviour.

Comment: From javadoc of set: Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set. 
Here this principle violated.

Comment: BTW, which java flavor you are using: oracle or openjdk? A bug was raised for OpenJdk remove method for set which talks about similar issue but was closed as not an issue: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8154740

Comment: @Ashutosh: I'm almost 100% that this is one area where the Oracle JDK will absolutely do what the OpenJDK does. There's no reason for them to divert in this area and doing so would actually be counter-productive for them. Edit: see the bottom of my answer for links to a bug with discussions on this.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*Something* changed about `HashSet` between Java 8 and Java 9, but the specifics are not actually that interesting, because the way you are using the `Set` is already [specified to be wrong](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (emphasis mine):

> Note: Great care must be exercised if mutable objects are used as set elements. **The behavior of a set is not specified if the value of an object is changed in a manner that affects equals comparisons while the object is an element in the set**.

Since [`Date.equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) depends on the time the `Date` represents, you do exactly that.

And since you do that the behavior of the set is no longer specified.

Which means it can misbehave in any way/shape/form and still be a conforming implementation.

You could try to find out *why* Java 9 specifically behaves differently now (I don't know myself), but it doesn't change the fundamental issue that *any* JVM could at any point in time behave differently yet again if you use the set the wrong way.

*Edit*: out of curiosity I *did* investigate what exactly was different and found a relevant change: In both OpenJDK 8 and 9 `HashSet` is implemented based on a `HashMap`, so this all focuses on `HashMap`.

In Java 8 [the `remove()` method of the relevant `Iterator` implementation](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l1438) contains this line:

```
K key = p.key;
removeNode(hash(key), key, null, false, false);
```

This re-hashes (i.e. gets the current hash) of the `key` (i.e. your `Date`) and tries to remove that from the `Map`. Since that new hash was never added in the first place (back when that key was added it had a different hash), this will not find a node and thus not remove anything.

In Java 9 [that code](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/file/65464a307408/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java#l1498) looks like this instead:

```
removeNode(p.hash, p.key, null, false, false);
```

This will simply pass the previously calculated-and-remembered hash `p.hash` to the `removeNode` method which will thus be able to find and remove the node in question.

The [changeset that introduced that change](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/jdk9/jdk/rev/4d74b5d2086c) mentions [this OpenJDK bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170733).

The comments in there (notably also by Doug Lea) seem to agree that "fixing" the behavior in the face of misused sets is not a goal, but that it could be faster to not re-compute the hash. In other words: that change was done for performance reasons and not for correctness reasons.

**So to summarize and re-iterate**: **both** of those behaviors are acceptable implementations, because by changing the `equals()` behavior of your set entries, you've broken the contract already.